# Panel dentro de otro panel

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo el siguiente problema: Quiero agregar dos paneles dentro de un panel que los contiene.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
        d1 = new Dimension(646, 699);
        contenedorMapaCanon = new PanelMapaCanon(d1);

        d2 = new Dimension(646, 100);
        contenedorCanon = new PanelCanon(d2);

        d3 = new Dimension(800, 900);
        contenedorMapa = new JPanel();
        contenedorMapa.setSize(d3);

        contenedorMapa.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));
        contenedorMapa.add(contenedorMapaCanon,0);
        contenedorMapa.add(contenedorCanon,1);
```

No me muestra nada, he probado con todos los Layouts que conozco pero nada.
¿Alguna idea? No es problema de que no muestre el contenido del Frame, ni que no añada la componente.

Comment: ¿En que parte del programa agregas a la ventana el `contenedorMapa`?, ¿Lo pusiste con un `add(contenedorMapa);` o `setContentPane(contenedorMapa)`?

Comment: add(contenderMapa), lo pongo al final del un método donde inicio todas la componentes.

Comment: Tienes que añadir los demás JPanel a tu JPanel prinicipal. Piensa que todos los JPanels los tienes que poner en `setVisible(true)` . Tampoco me ha quedado muy claro cuales son los `JPanels` secundarios y cual el primario. Pero normalmente el problema reside en alguno de los primeros. Yo te recomiendo que metas cada JPanel en un método, asi podrás diferenciarlos y tene run orden más claro a la hora de poner Buttons, TextFields, etc..